# Did you register the component correctly?

Tags: vue.js

As the title says, I'm having troubles with my Vue environment. Although my problem shares similarities with other topics here, I can't find a solution for my specific situation.

```html
<template>
  <div id="background">
    <Header />
    <Buttons />
    <Viewer />
    <SmartME />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from './components/Header.vue';
import Buttons from './components/Buttons.vue';
import Viewer from './components/Viewer.vue';

const SmartME = require('../../sources/SmartME').default;

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    SmartME,
    Header,
    Buttons,
    Viewer,
  },
};
</script>

<style>
  #background {
    background: lightgreen;
    margin: -8px;
  }
</style>
```

Here's the error console's log:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <SmartME> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <App> at src/App.vue
       <Root>
```

**EDIT:**

Feel free to ask me for more details about the issue (like screenshots and other code parts that you might find necessary for helping me.

Comment: It gives me error, as that comma is seen as "trailing comma". Without that, I can't run the environment.

Comment: can you share the component code for the `SmartMe` component? Any reason why it's `require` and not import? I'm not sure if `require` works in the default `vue-cli` setup.

Comment: Since the SmartME is nothing but a custom reworking of an already existing JavaScript source code, I used the `require` statement because it is exported using `module.exports = ...`

By the way, what do you mean with "component code for the SmartME component"?

Comment: is your `SmartME` component a vue component? Can you share the source code of that too?

Comment: It is a .js file, not a .vue one

Comment: it won't work as a vue component then. You can't do what you're trying to do.

What's the exported value of `require('SmartME').default`?

Comment: How can I see it?

Comment: Just `console.log` it? Anyway, I think it's going to be a bunch of JS helpers and not a tag `<SmartME />` like you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is related to using `require`. Why did you not use `import` like the others above it?

```js
import SmartME from '../../sources/SmartME';
```

or

```js
import { default as SmartME } from '../../sources/SmartME';
```

Depends how `SmartME` exports it's modules

Comment: Now the error given is `[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <SmartME>
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>`

I assume that this happens because `SmartME` is a JavaScript file and not a Vue one...

Comment: What? Are you sure it's a Vue component?

Comment: It's not indeed. As I said before, is a JavaScript file.

Comment: Then it won't work like that. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: It's the core of my project, without which my website would do nothing.

Comment: That's ok, but you can't use it as a vue component. You have to load it differently. But as I don't know anything about it, I can't suggest how